# Oracle, concurrency and global temporary tables

Tags: ruby, oracle, plsql, concurrency

I have a ruby application that loads data from oracle from different views. Each query has a large IN clause (thousands of ids) and I run into PGA limit error. I worked around this by creating a package the inserts the ids into a global temporary table and runs the sql with an exists clause against the table. It runs fine when not concurrent but when doing it concurrently, I get a (ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object).

```
  CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_ids_table (
    id NUMBER
  )
  on commit preserve rows;
  /
```

--

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test.bulk_query
  IS
    TYPE temp_ids IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

    FUNCTION run_query(ids IN temp_ids, query IN VARCHAR2) RETURN sys_refcursor;

  END bulk_query;
  /

  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test.bulk_query
  IS

    FUNCTION run_query(ids IN temp_ids, query IN VARCHAR2) RETURN sys_refcursor
    IS
      dataset SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. ids.count LOOP
        execute immediate 'INSERT INTO TEMP_IDS_TABLE (ID) VALUES (:id)' using ids(i);
      END LOOP;

      OPEN dataset FOR query;

      commit;

      RETURN dataset;
    END;
  END bulk_query;
  /
```

Comment: What line in the code you posted does the stack trace for the ORA-00955 point to?

Comment: Why `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` is needed at all in such situation. It can be done using a simple `IN` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Create (global temporary) table only once, before anything else you do. It'll be "permanent", meaning: its description will stay intact; **don't drop that table** (and then create it again and again).

Let anyone use it (through the procedure you wrote) as many times as they need it. Everyone will see only its own data; they won't be able to affect anyone else's rows.

Because, it seems that you are trying to create it for each user that is running the process - and that's wrong.

---

By the way, why dynamic SQL? Why don't you just *insert* those values into a table?

Comment: Thanks. I did create the global temporary table only once and I'm not dropping it.

How do I insert the array values into the table without looping over the array?

Comment: What is then causing "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object"?

Comment: I have no idea. It only happens when I run several queries concurrently. I was hoping someone here could shed some light.

Comment: Is this - what you posted - the whole code you're running?

Comment: This is all my plsql code. I have ruby code that calls this plsql function. Basically I pass in an array of ids, and the sql statement to execute.

Basically I call this function multiple times passing in different sql queries. An example sql statement that i pass is like this 
    "select * from foobar A where exists (select null 
    from temp_ids_table B where A.id = B.id)"

Comment: Huh, that's strange. If Ruby code isn't executing `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_ids_table`, then I don't see a reason why would Oracle complain.

Comment: Yeah. I created the temporary global table beforehand only one time.

Comment: Hmmm. Does your database use connection sharing?